# UIDatePicker missing hours with 24 hour / Irish locale

Tags: ios

So I'm loading a UIDatePicker and I set the locale to be the currentLocale, but when it appears the hour component is completely empty.

This only happens when the regional settings of the phone are 'Ireland (Irish)', and the time is set to be 24 hours. If I set it to be 'Ireland' then the hours appear fine as expected.

As far as I can tell this is a bug in iOS 6.0, but I'd love to be told otherwise.